# Draw imaginary numbers in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, numbers

i am trying to learn matlab. 
I am trying to make a program that draw these imaginary numbers: ("," = decimal number)

[image]

and determine what of the 500 numbers that is closest the real axis. 
And i need a little guidance.

What do i have to do to solve this task?
I was thinking about making a loop where all the "values" get stored in a array:

```
[code]
n= 1
while n < 500
    value=1+0.1^n;
    disp(value)
        n=n+1[/code]
```

(seems like value is printing wrong values? and how to store in a array?)
And then somehow determine what number that is nearest the real axis and then display the value.

would be really grateful if someone could help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the `,` in your formula is a decimal mark? If so please replace it with an `.` as it is used in english. The way you wrote it, it's a tuple with the elements `1+0` and `1i`

Comment: Your code misses at least an `i` to implement the formula.

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thats correct. "," is a decimal mark. will edit it, thanks for correcting me.
The letter "i" tells us that this is a imaginary number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB creates imaginary numbers by appending an `i` or `j` term with the number.  For example, if you wanted to create an imaginary number such that the real component was 1 and the imaginary component was 1, you would simply do:

```
>> A = 1 + i

A =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

You can see that there is a distinct real component as well as an imaginary component and is stored in `A`.  Similarly, if you want to make the imaginary component have anything other than 1, you would need to add a constant in front of the `i` (or `j`).  Something like:

```
>> A = 3 + 6i

A =

   3.0000 + 6.0000i
```

Therefore, for your task, you simply need to create a vector of `n` between `1` to `500`, input this into the above equation, then plot the resulting imaginary numbers.  In this case, you would plot the real component on the `x` axis and the imaginary component on the `y` axis.  Something like:

```
>> n = 1 : 500;
>> A = (1 + 0.1i).^n;
>> plot(real(A), imag(A));
```

[image]

`real` and `imag` are functions in MATLAB that access the real and imaginary components of complex numbers stored in arrays, matrices or single values.  As noted by knedlsepp, you can simply plot the array itself as `plot` can handle complex-valued arrays:

```
>> plot(A);
```

Nice picture btw!  Be mindful of the `.` operator appended with the `^` operator.  The `.` means an element-wise operation.  This means that we wish to apply the power operation for each value of `n` from `1` to `500` with `1 + 0.1i` as the base.  The result would be a 500 element array with the resulting calculations.  If we did `^` by itself, we would be expecting to perform a matrix power operation, when this is not the case.

The values that you want to analyze for each value of `n` being applied to the equation in your post are stored in `A`.  We then plot the real and imaginary components on the graph.  Now if you want to find which numbers are closest to the real axis, you simply need to find the smallest absolute imaginary component of the numbers stored in `A`, then search for all of those numbers that share this number.

```
>> min_dist = min(abs(imag(A)));
>> vals = A(abs(imag(A)) == min_dist)

vals =

   1.3681 - 0.0056i
```

This means that the value of `1.3681 - 0.0056i` is the closest to the real axis.

Comment: Nice answer you beat me by 1 min! +1 btw :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Ahaha, j'ai seulement de la chance mon ami. Merci!

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the top notch answer! 
I really apreciate it.
Do you have a paypal account? Would like to give you a few $ as thanks for the help.

Comment: @tofsti - My pleasure :) If you no longer need help, consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that is at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down arrows.  This signifies to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help.  Good luck!

Comment: @tofsti - Indeed I do :)  Go to my profile page.  You'll see a link there.  Thank you so much!  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng

Comment: @tofsti - That was a **very** generous tip.  Thank you one more time :)

Comment: @rayryeng: Seems we should be considering code4cash. BTW: `plot` should also feed on complex numbers.

Comment: @knedlsepp I didn't ask for cash. The OP offered and I didn't mind. I answer questions solely to benefit others. The cash was a bonus.

Comment: @rayryeng: Yeah, don't take it too serious. ;-) I was simply astonished by the fact that this just happened. (Considering you've answered more difficult questions!)

Comment: @knedlsepp Oh lol. Don't worry. I didn't take it seriously. I'm actually surprised myself. It's funny how SO works sometimes. The easier questions seem to give you more upvotes yet the difficult ones get no votes or no attention at all. Probably it's because the more difficult ones need a more specialized knowledge in comparison to the easier ones where more people are likely to understand the problem and solutions.

Comment: You can also use `1i` as the imaginary unit, which is more explicit and  makes your code more readable. (It also lets you use `i` and `j` as for-loop indices).

Comment: @ItamarKatz - That's true.  However, I avoid using `i` and `j` as `for` loop variables as it will shadow over `i` and `j` as complex variables.  Still good observation.

Comment: @knedlsepp dont worry. I guess that i will post a couple of more matlab questions in the future. I dont mind give some cash to people that provide really good answers, like rayreng  :) Its only fair...

Comment: You should! We will be more than happy to answer.